# Unable to display all the information except for first selection

Tags: python, list, maya

I am using the following code to process a list of images that is found in my scene, before the gathered information, namely the tifPath and texPath is used in another function.

However, example in my scene, there are 3 textures, and hence I should be seeing 3 sets of tifPath and texPath but I am only seeing 1 of them., whereas if I am running to check `surShaderOut` or `surShaderTex` I am able to see all the 3 textures info.

For example, the 3 textures file path is as follows (in the surShaderTex): `/user_data/testShader/textureTGA_01.tga, /user_data/testShader/textureTGA_02.tga, /user_data/testShader/textureTGA_03.tga`

I guess what I am trying to say is that why in my `for` statement, it is able to print out all the 3 results and yet anything bypass that, it is only printing out a single result.

Any advices?

```
surShader = cmds.ls(type = 'surfaceShader')
for con in surShader:
    surShaderOut = cmds.listConnections('%s.outColor' % con)
    surShaderTex = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % surShaderOut[0])   

path = os.path.dirname(surShaderTex)
f = surShaderTex.split("/")[-1]
tifName = os.path.splitext(f)[0] + ".tif"
texName = os.path.splitext(f)[0] + ".tex"
tifPath = os.path.join(path, tifName)
texPath = os.path.join(path, texName)

convertText(surShaderTex, tifPath, texPath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only two lines are part of your `for` loop. The rest only execute once.

So first this runs:

```
surShader = cmds.ls(type = 'surfaceShader')
for con in surShader:
    surShaderOut = cmds.listConnections('%s.outColor' % con)
    surShaderTex = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % surShaderOut[0])
```

Then after that loop, with only one `surShader`, one `surShaderOut`, and one `surShaderTex`, the following is executed *once*:

```
path = os.path.dirname(surShaderTex)
f = surShaderTex.split("/")[-1]
tifName = os.path.splitext(f)[0] + ".tif"
texName = os.path.splitext(f)[0] + ".tex"
tifPath = os.path.join(path, tifName)
texPath = os.path.join(path, texName)
```

Indent that the same as the lines above it, and it'll be run for *each* element of `surShader` instead of only once.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It works, thanks again! Can I ask supposedly the above code that I have typed belongs to `def getFileNames()`, and this time round I would wanted to grab the `texPath` in `getFileNames` to add it into this function - `getMeshInfo()`, though I added in `return texPath`, in the `getMeshInfo()` it fails to grab all the three paths, and is only grabbing the last selected info that it has...

Comment: `return` only runs once in a function, so you'll need to add the `texPath`s to a list (`texPaths = []`, followed by `texPaths.append(texPath)`. Then return the list

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well as your code. It works when I am testing it out for another variable but fails when I am testing it for the `texPath`, regardless or not I am making it as a global variable etc, probably due to the way the coding statement interprets. Nonetheless I am am to find a solution by having my function to integrate into `getFileNames()` and so far, it is working great with no issues :) Thanks again!